# How does a website recognize a smart phone?

Tags: web-development, website-design, website-features

I noticed that certain websites have a different "appearance/layout" when they recognize a cellphone being used.  How do they do this (preferably in a CSS, JS, and/or HTML context)?

Answer (score 2):

In general there are two possibilities:

1. recognizing of the display width
2. recognizing of device

**Media queries**

In the first case it works like measuring of current display width (or other parameters, like height, orientation etc.) and serving a stylesheets and other assets, like javascripts and images specially for this width. The simplest case are three socalled breakpoints, like something about 1024px (desktop), something about 700 pixel (tablet), something about 300 pixel (mobile).

Typical CSS media query could look like:

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    body {
        background-color: lightblue;
    }
}
```

Media query could implement not only a rule, but a file too, like:

```html
<link media="screen"
    href="/path/to/global.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link media="only screen and (max-width: 320px)"
    href="/path/to/touch.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link media="only screen and (max-width: 1024px)"
    href="/path/to/tablet.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link media="handheld"
    href="/path/to/mobile.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

or

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="cssbase.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="(min-width: 672px)" href="csswide.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="(orientation:landscape)" href="landscape.css">
```

The same media query done by javascript could look like:

```js
if (screen.width >= 600) {
    // download complicated script
    // swap in full-source images for low-source ones
}
```

**Device recognition**

In the second case different site versions (desktop, tablet, mobile) are served after recognition of user agent, containing in browser request header. Typical desktop user agent looks like

```
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.140 Safari/537.36
```

Device recognition with javascript could happen like:

```js
if (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i) != null){ 
  css.href = "/c/dropkick.css";
  var h = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
  h.appendChild(css);
}
```

or, with php, like:

```php
<?php if(strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Chrome')) { ?>
    Chrome
<?php } ?>
```

In this case the bigger the list of user agents is checked, the exacter one can recognize the user agent. This fact forces maintaining of long user agent lists or an access to third-party lists and/or libraries, like [mobile-detect.js](http://hgoebl.github.io/mobile-detect.js/).

Another point: user agent recognition should better happen on the server side - if on user side, it will fail if javascripts are off.

**privat opinion :)**

In my opinion the first possibility is working exacter as the second, because, specially on desktop and tablet devices user can manually change the display width.

But device recognition has its right to exist: with a kind of device recognition, like [device pixel ratio](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8785677/1992004) one can recognize whether the site should serve retina-ready images.

Comment: It is always better to use one CSS file: e.g `<link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css' type='text/css' media='all' />` and if you want the luxury of having easier administration using multiple files then use SASS.

Comment: @SimonHayter I wouldn't agree that it's "always better to use one CSS file" - while in this case it's true that the media queries are probably better off managed through SASS and a build process, with the move towards HTTP/2 it may be better to serve multiple smaller files as the connection overhead is reduced and more parallel requests can be handled.

Comment: @Zhaph-BenDuguid ~ I dunno what situation would ever make CSS more suitable in multiple files as demonstrated in this answer. The only ever time I would agree is using external CSS such as font awesome and Google fonts since these are cached on most people's machines before they even visit your site. So unless your site has massive CSS files that above the cache threshold on some older devices then I don't see the point. Less requests is better for the visitor and server regardless of HTTP/2 or not.

Comment: Yep, either for rather old, large CSS files, or moving to a more modular architecture where you only want to serve relevant content to your users. Sadly some larger sites I've worked on can have upwards of 70% "unused" CSS for any given page :(

Comment: But I agree that in this case it's unlikely that there will be much difference between the files to justify splitting them out.

Comment: Depends on how you look at it... if you have 10'000 visitors an hour and 4 CSS sheets that's equal to 30,000 additional GETS, the more visitors you have the more difference one style sheet becomes.

Comment: @SimonHayter i always thought, that it is better to have CSS files for desktop, mobile and print, and to serve them to those users, who are coming with certain devices, based on media queries and/or device recognition. With this setup you have more then one CSS file, but you server always only one of them, and this one much smaller, than it would be, if it would contain styles from CSS files for all devices. I mean, you have the same 10.000 visitors, but they don't get all three CSS files, but they get served only one CSS file, just for their device, and it is small.

Comment: @Evgeniy, you'd think it would work that way but sadly it doesn't. Browsers will download all spreadsheets regardless, because devices can change resolution and orientation, therefore they download these as the page firsts downloads. So all you are doing is making additional unnecessary server side requests.

Comment: I made a ***[demo](http://hcb.zant.co.uk/test/)*** for you to test with, simply check 'network' using Firefox Firebug or Chrome Inspect and click 'network' and then refresh the page. You will see that 3x CSS files are loaded regardless of the viewpoint. Try resizing the width of the page and reloading it in different viewpoints, all CSS are loaded. But with this said, even if browsers worked the way you would think they would these media files are often in a few kb's, hardly worth splitting in any case.

Answer (score -3):

By using the viewport meta tag in HTML and media queries in CSS. Looking for these keywords will bring up many useful tutorials.

Comment: This is not a high quality answer.   It is much more useful to write a few paragraphs here than to suggest that users search for answers.

Comment: I've already given the answer. You don't need to write a few paragraphs on something so simple.

Comment: Even simple questions deserve complete answers here.   Good answers contain enough information that users don't have to look elsewhere.   Good answers include references such as links to authoritative sources.    Please edit your answer to expand it.